# Updating state, gives empty state in react redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Am trying to make a login and add the return data to state, when I try to update state, it still gets empty state. I have added the code below, Please help me fix it. Am using RTK query to make the login mutation, and am new to this.

My AuthApi.js

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { api } from "./api";

export const authApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "authApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: api
    }),

    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        loginUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => {
                return {
                    url: "login",
                    method: "post",
                    body,
                };
            },
        }),
        registerUser: builder.mutation({
            query: (body) => {
                return {
                    url: "register",
                    method: "post",
                    body,
                };
            },
        }),
    }),
});

export const { useLoginUserMutation, useRegisterUserMutation } = authApi;
```

My userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { authApi } from "../../services/authApi";

const initialState = {
  role: null,
  accessToken: null,
  userData: null
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: (state) => {
      state.currentUser = null;
      state.errorMessage = ''
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builders) => {
    builders.addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.userData = action.payload.success.data
      state.accessToken = action.payload.success.accessToken
      state.role = action.payload.success.roles
    })
  }
})

export const { logout } = userSlice.actions

export const selectUser = (state) => state.user.accessToken

export default userSlice.reducer
```

my store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { authApi } from "../services/authApi";
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer,
        user: userReducer,
    },

    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authApi.middleware),
});

export default store;
```

`console.log(action.payload)` in userSlice `extraReducer` gives me the data in console, but it is not updating the state.